# Calculate values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I am still studying jquery and I have this code in my gsp:

```
<g:each in="${poundList}" var="poundInstance">
  <span>${poundInstance?.name}<span/>
  <span class="price">${poundInstance?.price}<span/>
</g:each>
  <span id="total"></span>
```

In my jquery:

```
function calculatePound() {
  totals= 0;
$(".price").each (function() {
    totals= totals+ parseFloat("0" + $(this).val());
});
$("#total").text(totals.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
calculatePound();
});
```

The code above has no errors. But the problem is that the `<'span id="total"'>` is empty or has a value of 0.0

What I was trying to do is to calculate the price of each poundInstance and display it.
How can I make it work using this code? Or I am too far from what I want to achieve?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), the method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. You can use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
function calculatePound() {
    var totals= 0;
    $(".price").each (function() {
        totals= totals+ parseFloat("0" + $(this).text());
    });
    $("#total").text(totals.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Also maybe it would be smart to interduce OP for the keyword `var`